# Windows Server 2012 - Access to registry denied when running powershell scripts from C#

Tags: c#, .net, powershell, windows-server-2012

I'm building a C# application that has to run some powershell scripts.

While the application works well on all my colleagues computers, I have issue having it to work properly on a Windows Server 2012 virtual machine.

Whenever I run a script through the application I'm getting the following error message:

> Access to the registry key 'HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\PowerShell\1\ShellIds\Microsoft.PowerShell' is denied. To change the execution policy for the default (LocalMachine) scope, start Windows PowerShell with the "Run as administrator" option. To change the execution policy for the current user, run "Set-ExecutionPolicy -Scope CurrentUser".

I precise that I went through a LOT of topics and tried many things that did not solve my problem
I tried:

set-executionpolicy unrestricted

set-executionpolicy unrestricted -Scope -CurrentUser

And of course I ran these commands on both x64 and x86 powershell instances (running the powershell application as administrator)

Now the strange part is that I have no trouble running the script through the powershell window directly, the error only occurs when running the script through the C# application.

Here's the code involved:

```
public static List<string> RunPowerShellScript(Sequence sq, Script script)
    {
        try
        {
            script.Results = new List<Result>();

            Runspace runspace = RunspaceFactory.CreateRunspace();
            runspace.Open();
            RunspaceInvoke runspaceInvoker = new RunspaceInvoke(runspace);
            //runspaceInvoker.Invoke("set-executionpolicy bypass");
            runspaceInvoker.Invoke("set-executionpolicy unrestricted");

            //Create a pipeline to send variables 
            Pipeline pipeline = runspace.CreatePipeline();

            //Create a command
            Command myCommand = new Command(Properties.Settings.Default.Scripts + "\\" + script.ScriptName + ".ps1", false);
            foreach (Parameter p in script.Parameters)
            {
                CommandParameter param = new CommandParameter(p.ParameterName, sq.GetUpdatedParameter(p));
                myCommand.Parameters.Add(param);
            }

            pipeline.Commands.Add(myCommand);

            //Return the output from the script
            Collection<PSObject> returnObjects = pipeline.Invoke();
            runspace.Close();

            List<string> output = new List<string>();
            foreach (PSObject po in returnObjects)
            {
                if (po != null)
                    output.Add(po.ToString());
            }

            return output;
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            return new List<string> { e.Message, "1" };
        }
    }
```

Comment: This may have something to do with you not running the powershell script in the same instance your running your execution policy change, try `powershell –ExecutionPolicy Bypass -File C:\Path\to\Script`. You will want to run this as a shell command (CMD) rather than a powershell command and it will knock the powershell script open.

Comment: I'm not sure what you're suggesting, should I change my c# code to run the script from cmd instead of using the RunspaceFactory ? Because, it does work from cmd indeed, but that's not new, it does work from the powershell windows as well, but not from the c# application

Comment: Use `System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("CMD.exe", powershell -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -File C:\Path\to\Script);'`That will open a cmd and run the Powershell script with execution policy bypassed

Comment: I'm gonna have to try that, that's not really convenient with my code and the dynamic passing of parameters but I'll give a shot

Comment: You can still pass in parameters, if you use `'System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("CMD.exe", str);'` then you can make `str` your exact command string, anything after the powershell part you can add params to add to your powershell script. e.g: `System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("CMD.exe", powershell -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -File C:\Path\to\Script param1 param2 param3);`

Comment: Well it seems to work somehow (not giving an error but not giving a result either, cmd window seems to be hanging..). However this is not really the solution I'm expecting, I'd like to be able to properly the return values of different scripts which the pipeline component has been made for. There must be a reason why this works on every computers but not on under Windows Server 2012

Comment: Use `Get-ExecutionPolicy -List` in a Powershell window to verify that your domain for the Windows Server is not overriding your policy change with a group policy. If it is, then there really isn't much you can do to change it without asking your domain administrator to change the GP

Comment: If the machine policy is overriding this then you can apply this in the registry as a fix `[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\Windows\PowerShell]
"ExecutionPolicy"=`

Comment: You just made me realize something trivial. I just resolved the issue by modifying my code to runspaceInvoker.Invoke("set-executionpolicy unrestricted -scope CurrentUser"); and now it works. I guess I had to define the scope inside the code of the application in order for it to be taken in account

Comment: Perfect! Glad it helped!

Answer (score 1):

To resolve this issue, Open powershell as an administrator and run the command again:

```
Set-ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted
```

Answer (score -1):

may be this can solve your problem:

1- open "Visual Studio" az administrator
2- open your project solution ***with visualstudio***
3- run it

Comment: Unfortunately, the windows server is not the dev machine, and the application must run without the help of visual studio